# C++ namespace accessible via argument?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'm having trouble understanding function resolution across namespaces. In particular, can someone shed some light on some unexpected behavior on the following code?:

```
namespace Foo {
struct Thing {};
void Bar(int) {}
void Baz(Thing) {}
} // namespace Foo

void Test() {
  Foo::Thing thing;
  Bar(42); // error: 'Bar' was not declared in this scope
  Baz(thing); // Works???
  return 0;
}
```

In the code above, calling the unqualified `Bar` does not work, as expected, because it is neither fully qualified (`::Foo::Bar`) nor implicit (`using namespace Foo`, or defining `Test` within the `Foo` namespace). But for some reason, the unqualified `Baz(Foo::Thing)` *does* resolve without error. Can someone explain why the second call is resolved while the first call is not? And what are the general rules for this kind of resolution?

I always thought that if I wasn't within a namespace, or an object of that namespace, then I never had implicit access to that namespace. Obviously I was wrong, at least in one case.

Comment: Mhm, it's called [argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

Comment: Not related, but `return 0` shouldn't be there in a `void` function.

Comment: In which namespace should the compiler lookup for an integer argument? For the second case `thing` is a good enough hint.